# Is there a packaged runtime redistributable with FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

In our environment, we have a server farm, each server running a number of tasks. The task binary packages are deployed (and tasks are run) with an in-house scheduling system.

When a new *common* dependency on Microsoft libraries or runtimes is introduced, that dependency is normally pushed as a server-wide upgrade (for example, a Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package). Currently, the servers have a package named Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime installed, and also have FSharp.Core version 4.0.0.0 in the GAC which came I have no idea whence, but  FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 is not commonly available.

Is there a redistributable package for Visual F# 3.0 that would deploy FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 into the GAC, or should we instead include a copy of FSharp.Core.dll with each task binary? Indeed, I would avoid having hundreds of copies of a common DLL if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Likely answer**

I'd be happy to be wrong and will gladly remove this answer, but I have to conclude there is no redistributable package exists that would install a system-wide copy of FSharp.Core version 4.3.0.0 into the GAC.

**Hack around the issue**

The following WIX script creates the .MSI package that installs the assembly and NGen's it. Of course, testing was limited, so use it only if you really need an MSI package to roll out the assembly. To expressly disperse any hint of possible copyright issues, I am releasing the code to the public domain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  This installs FSharp.Core.dll 4.3.0.0 (that comes with Visual Studio
  2012) into the GAC and then NGens it for both 32 and 64 bits.

  Component ID 61F15BE3-6844-46F3-8E8E-3C81A8DBBFCB and keypath
  FSharp_Core_Dll_GAC_File were obtained from VS2012 RTM install DVD,
  file \packages\professionalcore\Setup\vs_professionalcore.msi.
  Other IDs here match those in the Microsoft file for easier reference.
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Microsoft F# 3.0 Core Redistributable (4.3.0.0)" Language="1033" Version="4.3.0.0"
           Manufacturer="YOUR COMPANY HERE" UpgradeCode="5271a7ee-8baa-4348-aff7-edb114090cee">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Feature Id="FsCore" Title="Microsoft F# Core Libraries" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="Redist4.0_GAC_FSharp.Core.dll" />
    </Feature>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="GAC" Name="GAC">
        <Component Id="Redist4.0_GAC_FSharp.Core.dll" Guid="61F15BE3-6844-46F3-8E8E-3C81A8DBBFCB">
          <File Id="FSharp_Core_Dll_GAC_File" Name="FSharp.Core.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net"
                Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll">
            <netfx:NativeImage Id="FSharp_Core_Dll_GAC_File_32" Platform="32bit" Priority="1" Debug="no" Dependencies="no" />
            <netfx:NativeImage Id="FSharp_Core_Dll_GAC_File_64" Platform="64bit" Priority="1" Debug="no" Dependencies="no" />
          </File>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Copy this script to a file `fscore.wxs`, verify path to the installed reference assembly, and generate an MSI file as (also adjust paths to WIX installation)

```
candle -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.9\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll" fscore.wxs
light.exe -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.9\bin\\WixNetFxExtension.dll" -out FSCoreRedist4300.msi -spdb -sval fscore.wixobj
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/) for just FSharp.Core, and [a redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44011) that also includes compiler tools.

Comment: The former is not very relevant, since we cannot use NuGet packages to update servers. To clarify, is the latter *the* redistributable package that should be installed on server? We do not need compiler tools on servers. Is not there a package without the tools?

Comment: Of course you can use NuGet packages to update servers. They're just zip files - write a script to extract the assemblies to the GAC if you can't find one already-written. The NuGet package IS the package without the tools. [Welcome to the future of .NET development](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2014/12/19/Building-future-NET-projects-is-quite-pleasant.aspx). Personally, we just redistribute FSharp.Core.dll with our other dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is not correct. I just installed the redistributable package 3.1.2 as you suggested, and it added two versions of FSharp.Core into the GAC: 2.3.0.0 and 4.3.1.0. Our applications still fail to load when trying to bind to 4.3.0.0. Apparently, there is no machine redirect policy installed with this package.

Comment: Regarding NuGet: I do have a copy of the core v 4.3.0.0 obviously, it came with VS2012 to the best of my knowledge, so I do not need to install it from anywhere. But the installation on servers requires at least calling the Fusion API to put the assembly into the GAC: you cannot just "extract a package into the GAC", unless I am missing something profound.

Comment: I was glossing over exactly what the script would have to do to get the assembly into the GAC. If your scripting language is PowerShell, [here's a project that might help](https://powershellgac.codeplex.com/). Otherwise you'd have to call the Fusion API yourself. I'm afraid this still won't install any machine-wide redirect policies for you, though. I don't know of any packages that do that for you - you might have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, really, although I must admit I am not getting a workable solution yet. Out IT guys are using Chef to roll out server changes, and NuGet we are only using internally for project dependencies. If all else fails, I'll rather write an MSI installer in WIX to install the assembly in GAC and NGen them, than adding NuGet into the bigger IT picture. Should be even easier, methinks. And Happy New Year! :-)

Comment: > we cannot use NuGet packages to update servers. 

Curious: How do you deploy all your Nuget dependencies right now? Can't you use the same technique for F#? Why use the GAC at all?

Comment: @Grundoon: This was in the question: A custom deployment system that deploys a custom packaged binary. What I want to avoid is having deployed hundreds of copies of FSharp.Core (or other standard Microsoft libraries), therefore GAC.

Comment: FYI, it's looking like in .NET vNext, pretty much all standard MS libraries are going to be NuGet packages. I don't know if that means they're dropping MSI installers or not.

Comment: @kkm If you control the machine but can't use gacutil, what about installing into a shared directory using the codebase element in machine.config?

Comment: @Grundoon: Technically not incorrect, but this would likely reintroduce the "DLL hell" problem that GAC is concieved to quench. Only some binary packages ran on the server depend on F#.Core 4.3.0.0; others depend on 4.0.0.0, while other will use 4.3.1.0, as developers start using F# 3.1. Of these, only the 4.3.0.0 will be in the shared location. Now think what happens if MS comes with another non-GAC'ed FSharp.Core.dll. If anyone would take the shared folder approach, then these 2 (and more future) DLLs files would fight each other for their place there.

Answer (score 2):

The download linked in Joel Mueller's answer (also [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44011)) is the official installer from Microsoft.  It contains the compiler, interactive, multiple versions of the runtime, and the Visual Studio integration binaries.

The VS integration bits are only deployed if VS is installed (dev scenario).  Otherwise, it will just install the compiler/interactive/runtime (server scenario).

Only the latest version of the runtime (4.3.1.0 at this time) is GACed by the installer, but various other versions are deployed, as well, including 4.3.0.0.

Adding assemblies to the GAC is very easy. Just run `gacutil /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll"` as admin.

Comment: A problem here is that there is no `gacutil` on servers, since this is an SDK tool. I happen to use the same [powershell extension](https://powershellgac.codeplex.com/) that he also suggested, and this extension can install assemblies onto GAC. But this is no automated way of deploying changes. I know that out IT can roll out updates in the form of executables and MSI.